# 現金 and 金 what are the similarity and difference in usage?

Tags: word-choice

As the topic of this post what are differences and similarities in usage of 現金 and 金?  Some examples of differences would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would you perhaps have any examples of their usage, and/or what do you understood about those words from your research?

Answer (score 2):

現金 げんきん means cash, while 金 かね means money.

Comment: Does this means 金 かね is more general than 現金 げんきん?

Comment: Yes. But please note 金 かね sounds a bit blunt. お金 おかね is polite form.